# Websocket is not working with WSS in Apache

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

Let me explain you the whole scenario in detail:

We have two servers:
- one with shared hosting
- other is VPS

Our requirement is to setup the websocket in the project. but to do so, the shared hosting doesn't allow to open the custom port. so we decided to buy another "VPS" server.

check below image:

[image]

As you can see in above image, our webportal uses VPS server for websocket connection.

Shared hosting is HTTPS.
And VPS server has also SSL. so it is also HTTPS.

---

so if I connect web portal with "ws" as below:

```
var wsocket = new WebSocket("ws://DOMAIN_NAME_OF_VPS:PORT")
```

then it gives error as below:
"Mixed content : The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over Https, but attepmted to connect to the insecure websocket endpoint 'ws://DOMAIN_NAME_OF_VPS:PORT'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS."

so it is obvious that we cannot use WS in HTTPS.

so we simply replace WS with WSS as below (ofcousre we install SSL certificate):

```
var wsocket = new WebSocket("wss://DOMAIN_NAME_OF_VPS:PORT")
```

Now I am getting this error : websocket connection to 'wss://DOMAIN_NAME_OF_VPS:PORT' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out.

---

**About websocket server (vps server):**

I am using Ratchet for websocket integration in PHP.
http://socketo.me/

I am using Apache engine for PHP.

---

**Ratchet server code :**

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

use Chat\Chat;

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat)), 19994);

$server->run();

?>
```

**000-default file is :**

- I already tried some ProxyPass which is commented in code. Please help if I have done wrong code.

  # ServerAdmin vps-server-domain
      ServerName vps-server-domain

  ```
  DocumentRoot /var/www/ 
  SSLEngine on 
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/vps-server-domain_private.key 
  SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/vps-server-domain.crt 
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/vps-server-domain.ca-bundle

  # SSLProxyEngine On
  # ProxyRequests Off 

  # ProxyPass "/wss/"  "ws://vps-server-domain:19994/"
  # ProxyPass "/wss2/"  "ws://vps-server-domain:19994/"
  # ProxyPass /wss2/  "ws://vps-server-domain:19994/"
  # ProxyPass /ws/ wss://vps-server-domain:19994/

  <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
  </Directory>

  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
      AllowOverride None
      Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  # RewriteEngine on
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule .* wss://vps-server-domain:19994%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
  ```

---

If I use http in the web portal, and use "ws" for websocket, then everything works fine.

so I do not understand why "wss" is not working with "https", while I have integrated SSL in VPS.

*Is there any other way to tell websocket to use SSL files?*

*Am I missing something?*

Your help will be very important for me.

Thank you very much,
Happy new year in advance.

Comment: You didn't post the actual URL you've used in JS. Is it pointing directly to your PHP script?